# CPTXYScatterPlot - Can I set the Z order of plot symbols?

Tags: core-plot

[image: Core Plot bubble chart]

Using Core Plot's CPTScatterPlot, I've made a bubble chart that looks like the above.

I've implemented `plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex` in my delegate so I can detect when the user touches one of the bubbles.  Using this screenshot as an example, I want to be able to highlight the yellow bubble and bring it in front of the red one when the user touches it.  In  graphical terms, I want to set the Z order of the selected `CPTPlotSymbol` to be higher than the others.  How can I accomplish that?  I'm able to highlight the selected bubble by drawing it in a different color in my `symbolForScatterPlot` method, but I can't seem to find a way to make it draw in front of the overlapping symbol.

Comment: I would liket to generate such a plot. Could you please answer this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641601/ios-core-plot-scatter-plot-symbol-color-appearance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Plot draws the data points in the order they appear in the datasource. You'll need to reorder the data so the top-most bubble is at the last index and call `-reloadData` on the plot to tell it to refresh its data. If you have the data points in an array, sort it by the desired z-index (back to front) and use the sorted array to feed the datasource.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured, but I was hoping there was an easier way that I was missing.  Thanks for the answer.